# Calling ::CreateFile for a modem in C++ always returning ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION

Tags: c++, windows, createfile

I have a modem on COM44 and when I try to access it via C++ I end up receiving ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.  The code I am using is and m_hFile ends up as -1:

```
void* m_hFile;
m_hFile = ::CreateFile( "\\\\.\\COM44",
  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  NULL,
  NULL );
```

I have tested access to the modem via Putty and was able to open its comport and send AT commands to it without any problem so I know it works.

Comment: Silly question maybe, but the Putty connection is closed right? Sometimes windows just thinks a resource is in use, have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes the putty connection is closed.  I tried putty after spending an hour trying to get this to work including rebooting the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ends up not being with the CreateFile code but with the registry code I have above it which determines the com port number to use which I hadn't added because I didn't think it was relevant.